# Hamiltonicity in graphs of small diameter

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, hamiltonicity

Consider a graph of small diameter, say $O(1)$. Intuitively, it seems that such graphs have a much better chance of being Hamiltonian, since you must be able to "get around" the graph easily. However, I'm unsure how to formalize this; is there any known criteria for such graphs being Hamiltonian?

My main thought has been that Ore's theorem (if $deg(x) + deg(y) \ge n$ for every pair of non-adjacent vertices, then the graph is Hamiltonian) might be helpful, since if some non-adjacent vertices have small degrees, they may force a large diameter, but I'm unconvinced that there are not counterexamples to this idea.

Answer (score 2):

If the diameter is $1$ then the graph is complete, so it is hamiltonian for $n\geq 3$.

If the diameter is at least $2$ then we can find a counterexample of arbitrary size by taking the start on $n$ vertices. And if we want the radius to be exactly $k$ we can append a path to one of the leafs of the star.

In general you can consider any graph with at least one vertex of degree $1$.

Comment: I think that most graphs are hamiltonian for large $n$, so if we also add the condition that the radius be bounded, then most graphs with bounded degree will also be hamiltonian.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I think the star is a useful counterexample for myself to keep in mind to improve intuition for this question. What I'm ideally looking for is a known criteria for graphs of bounded diameter to be Hamiltonian, something like (just an example of format not a meaningful idea) a graph of diameter d is Hamiltonian if its minimum degree is at least d.

Comment: If somoething like that exists I would be very shocked